# Python script that reads a Json and converts it to a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I have a JSON that I can catch her from the Web or download on my Linux... And I need to assemble a standardized code from this JSON.

I need to assemble a JavaScript always standard with as modifications that come from my JSON.

I need to change two values in my JavaScript.

Today currently works right, plus I that manual mount, wanted to assemble this automatica using Python or JavaScript.

My JSON:

```
{
    "home": [
        {
            "base_url": "home",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "portal": [
        {
            "base_url": "portal",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "digital": [
        {
            "base_url": "digital",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }

    ]
}
```

My Java Script:

```js
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
     const headers = request.headers;
     const uri = request.uri;

     var origin = request.origin[0].custom.domainName;
     console.log(`Request #PATH# is "${uri}"`);
     console.log(`Request #INCOMING REQUEST ORIGIN# set to "${origin}"`);
    
     const regex = /^\/(digital|home|portal|)[^\/]*/i;  // **<<<< HERE**
     if (regex.test(request.uri))
     {
             /* Set custom origin fields*/
             request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: 'www.testemestradoolpt.com.br' // **<< HERE**
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: '*'}];
             /**origin = request.origin.custom.domainName;  enable it for testing*/
    }
    /** for testing purposes don't use unless you need to, big performance hit
    console.log(`###### - > Request HOST "${request.headers.host[0].value}"`);
    console.log(`###### - > Final Request Origin Server "${origin}"`);
    */
    callback(null, request);
};
```

If you notice I just need to add my `base_url` that comes from my JSON in the regular JavaScript expression field and only once the type that and the URL in the other field, the URL will always be the same.

I made a python script that brings me the base URL, more I need a python script that mounts to min the Javascript with the variables of the JSON as the Javascript above I sent, and I'm having a lot of trouble doing that , follow what I could do in Python:

```py
import json

with open('dataload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data ['home']:
         print(p['base_url'])
```

Comment: have you tried using [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#template-strings)?

Comment: no,I am with the doubt PQ I have never programmed in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string.Template to easily substitute values in a string,
i am not entirely sure what parts of the json you want to use to fill the template. below is one approach.

```py
import json
from string import Template

# load the template
with open("template.js", "rt") as template_file:
    js_template = Template(template_file.read())

with open('dataload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# select data
base = data["home"][0]["base_url"]
url = data["home"][0]["type"]

# fill the template with the selected data
print(js_template.safe_substitute(base=base, url=url))
```

template.js

```js
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
     const headers = request.headers;
     const uri = request.uri;

     var origin = request.origin[0].custom.domainName;
     console.log(`Request #PATH# is "${uri}"`);
     console.log(`Request #INCOMING REQUEST ORIGIN# set to "${origin}"`);

     const regex = /^\/($base)[^\/]*/i;  // **<<<< HERE**
     if (regex.test(request.uri))
     {
             /* Set custom origin fields*/
             request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: '$url' // **<< HERE**
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: '*'}];
             /**origin = request.origin.custom.domainName;  enable it for testing*/
    }
    /** for testing purposes don't use unless you need to, big performance hit
    console.log(`###### - > Request HOST "${request.headers.host[0].value}"`);
    console.log(`###### - > Final Request Origin Server "${origin}"`);
    */
    callback(null, request);
};
```

output

```
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
     const headers = request.headers;
     const uri = request.uri;

     var origin = request.origin[0].custom.domainName;
     console.log(`Request #PATH# is "${uri}"`);
     console.log(`Request #INCOMING REQUEST ORIGIN# set to "${origin}"`);

     const regex = /^\/(home)[^\/]*/i;  // **<<<< HERE**
     if (regex.test(request.uri))
     {
             /* Set custom origin fields*/
             request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: 'www.testemestradoolpt.com.br' // **<< HERE**
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: '*'}];
             /**origin = request.origin.custom.domainName;  enable it for testing*/
    }
    /** for testing purposes don't use unless you need to, big performance hit
    console.log(`###### - > Request HOST "${request.headers.host[0].value}"`);
    console.log(`###### - > Final Request Origin Server "${origin}"`);
    */
    callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your huge help so that's exactly what I wanted

I tested it worked correctly.

more missing a detail that I can not do, maybe you can help me.


on the line  

    const regex = /^\/(home)[^\/]*/i;  // **<<<< HERE**

I need to return all positions of the example json:

    const regex = /^\/(digital|home|portal|)[^\/]*/i; // **<<<< HERE**


And from the test I did it always returns home only, even though json has the values of home, portal and digital.

I tried to do everything for him to read the other keys, but as I am new to python I'm having a hard time